# Can we have multiple android projects in One Work space in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am new to android and i want to know if it is possible to have multiple android projects in a single worksapce. I am using eclipse.

Comment: Can any one tell me the steps to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a new project: `File`, then `New`, then `Android Application Project`.

To import an existing project: `File`, then `Import...`, then `Existing Projects into Workspace`.

Answer (score 4):

Just create or import new project in the left panel - Package explorer....)))))

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possibly, and in fact the usual way to do it ;P

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely possible. Add as many projects as you want. I would suggest using working sets to group them as well by right clicking on a project and selecting assign working sets.